# Using Q - how to call an object's async function that updates object properties

Tags: node.js, q

I’m using Q promises with NodeJS and my code is not working as expected.

I have an array of type ObjA. Each ObjA has a property, objB, of type ObjB. 
ObjB has an async method called extract that does an async task and sets / updates objB properties. I use `Q.defer` in the async function and return the deferred promise.

I add the deferred promise to an array and call `Q.all`.
This part works as expected and `objB.exract` is called (I have verified via `console.log`).

But when I subsequently output the results, objB properties haven't changed (even though I set them in extract).

Here is the code:

```
//file ObjA.js

exports.ObjA = function(data)
{
this._id = data.id;
this._created_at = data.created_at;
this._objB = new ObjB.ObjB(data.somefield);
};

//file ObjB.js

exports.ObjB = function(data)
{
    this._afield = data;
    this._bfield = '';
    this._cfield = '';
};

exports.ObjB.prototype.extract = function()
{
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    async_call(this._afield, function(e, resp)
    {
        if (e)
        {
            console.log(e);
            return deferred.reject(e);
        }
        else
        {
            this._bfield = resp.val1;
            this._cfield = resp.val2;
            console.log(this._bfield + ", " + this._cfield);
            return deferred.resolve(resp);
        }
     };
    return deferred.promise;
};

//main file,

var alist = [];
// code to populate alist with objects of type ObjA
var queue = [];
for (var i=0; i<alist.length; i++)
{
    queue.push(alist[i]._objB.extract());
}

Q.all(queue).then(function(succ)
    {
        console.log('final values');
        console.log(alist);
    },
      function(err)
    {
        console.log(err)
    }
    );
```

When I run this, extract is correctly called and `this._bfield` and `this._cfield` are correctly output from the `console.log`.
But then it comes to the success function for `Q.all()` and it prints 'final values', followed by '' for `objB._bfield` and `objB._cfield`.

Why are the values set in extract not being printed? I'm guessing this has something to do with object references but can't pinpoint what is wrong here.

Any help would be much much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

be care of 'this' keyword, replace this piece of code :

```
async_call(this._afield, function(e, resp)
{
    if (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
        return deferred.reject(e);
    }
    else
    {
        this._bfield = resp.val1;
        this._cfield = resp.val2;
        console.log(this._bfield + ", " + this._cfield);
        return deferred.resolve(resp);
    }
 };
```

to:

```
var that = this;
async_call(this._afield, function(e, resp){
    if (e)
    {
        console.log(e);
        deferred.reject(e);
    }
    else
    {
        that._bfield = resp.val1;
        that._cfield = resp.val2;
        console.log(that._bfield + ", " + that._cfield);
        deferred.resolve(resp);
    }
 });
```